# How to optimize a large HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css

We recently had to switch from .txt based logfiles to .html.
Reasons are that we could easily filter categories, apply colors to text etc...

Our logfiles are a plain old html file, with all resources included (inline css, inline js, ...). Every message is a `<div>` with some classes applied (like `timestamp` or `category_foo`)

This works really well for small logfiles. Unfortunately with larger log files (starting at 3MB) there are a variety of problems. Our logfiles can easily get bigger than 100MB.

We have a filtering system as well that uses javascript to hide all messages containing a specific class (to filter by categories).

One optimization we did already was to not modify the DOM elements directly, but instead add a new `<style>` tag to the head of the html. That way we can easily add `display:none;` to all the messages. That has already helped a lot, but its not enough.

In what ways could we optimize this? In chrome the loading of even a 30mb file takes many minutes. Is there some way we can optimize the file somehow to make it easier for the browser to load?
Could we maybe paginate the log somehow, even though all content is inside the html file?

In order to make logging as fast as possible at runtime, our application starts by writing a "template" html. And then it just keeps appending lines like this

`<div class='categoryInfo'>Some Info Text</div>`

Comment: dump them to a database and use some simple queries to only grab what you need to see

Comment: I was about to tell the same! Dump all logs into a database, then you can create a full text index on everything. You're using a "webpage" as a database, and that's not what it was intended for...

Comment: I am guessing that your js filtering fires after the browser loads and renders the html, so in your initial load you are actually showing all which might be what takes so long. I would add a display: none to the container of all messages, and then in the js filter the messages you actually want and then remove the display : none from parent container. This way you could also paginate what you show. It all depends if what is taking minutes is the screen rendering or html load + html parsing though

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments of your question, the logical solution would be to put them in a database. Of course you could store them in a text format if you want maximum accessibility.

You could create a simple script that queries this database and outputs a webpage. *(e.g. using PHP on Apache 2)* This makes working with 'log' files way easier. Those simple PHP scripts, in combination with your already existing JS, could be way more powerful/productive. This way you keep information storage, processing and markup away from each other, like it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You might have painted yourself into a corner there: by switching to html as your logfile format, you have made it harder to use existing tools that handle log files.

I assume your original intention was to make viewing and filter the log file easier. I fear you just made it harder.

The alternative would be to make your logfile more machine readable, and look into tools that then help you read, filter, search it.  for example:

- https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash